# Random variable exercise

Tags: probability, random-variables

given the random variables $X$ and $Y$, such that

$Pr\{X=1\} = Pr\{X=2\} = Pr\{X=3\} = Pr\{X=4\} = Pr\{X=5\} = \frac15$

and

$Pr\{Y=1\} = \frac12$, $Pr\{Y=2\} = Pr\{Y=3\} = Pr\{Y=4\} = Pr\{Y=5\} = \frac18$,

where $Pr\{\}$ represents the probability that a random variable takes on a certain value, compute:

1) $Pr\{X > Y\}$;

2) the probability that $X + Y$ is odd;

3) the conditional probability of "$X$ is even" given "$X + Y$ is odd".

Could you help me to solve this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: Probably the two random variables are independent. You should add that in the question.  If this is the case, for the first question you should find $P(X>Y) = \sum_{y=1}^5 P(X>Y, Y = y)$. Can you compute this?

Comment: @Cornelis Yes, I can. It result $\frac{11}{20}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Hint: As $\Pr(X>x) = 1-\frac{x}{5}$, can you find $\Pr(X>Y) = \sum_{x=2}^{5} \Pr(X>x)\Pr(Y=y)\quad$  (assuming $X\perp Y$)

2) Hint: $\newcommand{\odd}{\operatorname{odd}}\newcommand{\even}{\operatorname{even}} \Pr(\odd(X+Y)) = \Pr(\odd(X),\even(Y)) + \Pr(\even(X),\odd(Y))$

3) To evaluate $\Pr(\even(X)\mid \odd(X+Y))$ use the definition of conditional probability (and the above).

Comment: I don't understand how to evaluate $Pr\{even(X), odd(X+Y)\}$. Can you help me ?

Comment: Obviously it is $\Pr(\even(X), \odd(X+Y))= \Pr(\even (X), \odd(Y))$